# TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined props using Jest and React. Why?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

Trying to write unit tests for the ReactJs code using Jest. When I am trying to pass the props it shows me below error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

```
  62 | 
  63 | const mapStateToProps = state => {
> 64 |   const { email, password, errors, loading } = state.auth;
     |           ^
  65 | 
  66 |   return { email, password, errors, loading };
  67 | };
```

SignIn.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import * as actions from "Actions";
import classnames from "classnames";

class SignIn extends Component {
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { email, password } = this.props;
    this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
  }

  render() {
    const { email, password, errors, fieldChanged } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="contentWrapper">
        ....
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SignIn.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fieldChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  password: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { email, password, errors, loading } = state.auth;

  return { email, password, errors, loading };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  actions
)(SignIn);
```

SignIn.test.js

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Enzyme, {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import SignIn from '../containers/authentication/SignIn';
import mapStateToProps from "../containers/authentication/SignIn";

const mockStore = configureMockStore();

describe('SignIn', () => {

  it('render sign in', () => {
      const state = {
          email: "aaky8668@gmail.com",
          password: "pass123"
      };

      const store = mockStore(state);
      const dwrapper = Enzyme.mount(<SignIn store={store} />);
      console.log(dwrapper);
      expect(dwrapper.props().email).toBe("aakshay8668@gmail.com")  
  });
});
```

Need to unit test SignIn and getting this error, how to map state with props?

What will be the correct way to map state with props.

Comment: Wrap your component with a react-redux `Provider` and pass the store into it: `<Provider store={store}><Signin /><Provider>`. An easier approach would be to `export` the `class` and import it for your test: `import { Signin } from './path';` so you wont have to deal with the Redux (instead you'll just pass props directly into the component and manipulate them accordingly).

Comment: That issue got resolved with {SignIn}, thanks @MattCarlotta. Now getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined
          const dwrapper = shallow(<SignIn {...props} />);
    
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined

> 40 |       const dwrapper = shallow(<SignIn {...props} />);

Answer (score 0):

The line of

```
const { email, password, errors, loading } = state.auth;
```

is attempting to destructure `state.auth`, it attempts to store its `email`, `password`, `errors`, `loading` members into variables with the same names. The error `indicates that` `state.auth` is `undefined`. You will need to make sure that state exists, it has an `auth` member which has attributes of the names that your code above expects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a proponent of bypassing the redux portion and testing against `actions` and `reducers` independently. Therefore, I'd recommend exporting the `class` and importing that for your test.

**Working example** (click the `Tests` tab to run tests):

[image: Edit Protected Route - Redux]

---

**containers/Login/index.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../../actions/Auth";
import Form from "../../components/Form";
import SubTitle from "../../components/SubTitle";
import Title from "../../components/Title";

export class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  };

  handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) =>
    this.setState({ [name]: value });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { email, password } = this.state;
    if (!email || !password) return;

    this.props.login(email);
  };

  render = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <Title>Login</Title>
      <SubTitle>You must login before viewing the dashboard!</SubTitle>
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          name="email"
          type="email"
          className="uk-input"
          placeholder="email"
          value={this.state.email}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input
          className="uk-input"
          name="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit">
          Login
        </button>
      </Form>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

Login.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { login }
)(Login);
```

**containers/Login/__tests__/Login.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { Login } from "../index";

const login = jest.fn();

const initProps = {
  login
};

describe("Login", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Login {...initProps} />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    login.mockClear();
  });

  it("renders without errors", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("form").exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("calls handleChange class field to update an input with a value", () => {
    const value = "test@test.com";
    wrapper
      .find("input")
      .first()
      .simulate("change", { target: { value, name: "email" } });

    expect(wrapper.state("email")).toEqual(value);
    expect(
      wrapper
        .find("input")
        .first()
        .props().value
    ).toEqual(value);
  });

  it("doesn't call 'login' prop if email or password fields are empty", () => {
    wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");

    expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });

  it("calls 'login' prop to log in a user", () => {
    const email = "test@test.com";
    wrapper.setState({ email, password: "password" });
    wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");

    expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledWith(email);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> SignIn.test.js
>
> > The key too solution is that we have to add dive() to the shallow component so that it could get the component wrapper completely, this solution worked for me

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, configur } from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
import SignIn from '../containers/authentication/SignIn';
import configureStore from '../configureStore';

Enzyme.configure({
    adapter: new EnzymeAdapter(),
    disableLifecycleMethods: true
});

describe('SignIn', () => {
  it('render sign in', () => {
     const state = {
          auth: {
            email: "test@test.com",
            password: "password",
            errors: {
              login: "red"
            },
            loading: true
          }          
      };

      const store = configureStore(state);
      const dwrapper = shallow(<SignIn store={store}/>).dive();
      expect(dwrapper.find(".contentWrapper").exists()).toBeTruthy();  
  });
});
```