# Properly Configure a Combined Redux Store with Enzyme/Jest in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

My store is composed of combined reducers. I'm trying to mount my first component and am running into issues of nesting:

```
loginTest: 

import React from "react";
import {shallow } from "enzyme";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import Login from "./login";

const store = configureStore([thunk])();

const props = {
  auth: {
    errorMessage: "Oops not correct",
    authenticated: true,
  },
};

const wrapper = shallow(<Login {...props} store={store} />).dive();
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'errorMessage' of undefined

  79 | function mapStateToProps(state) {
  80 |   return {
> 81 |     errorMessage: state.auth.errorMessage,
     |                              ^
  82 |     authenticated: state.auth.authenticated,
  83 |   };
  84 | }
```

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446441/typeerror-cannot-read-property-email-of-undefined-props-using-jest-and-react. Either wrap your component with a `Provider` and `mount` (not recommended) or export the class/function, to bypass redux, and test `actions` and `reducers` separately (recommended). See here for working test example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447746/7376526

Comment: @MattCarlotta wouldn't i still need to wrap the component with the Provider if the component is connected?

Comment: No, if you export the class/function, you're just importing/exporting the unconnected component (the default export is connected). Take a look at my working example, where I'm `export class Login extends Component` and `import { Login } from "../index";`. Using brackets `{ Example  }`, tells webpack to look for a specific export named `Example`.